# What is wrong with my squeeze() function?

Tags: c, loops, char, c-strings, function-definition

Right now I'm working my way through "The C Programming Language" book and boy has it been a humbling experience. Right now I'm working on exercise 2-3 in the book and I can't figure out where I've gone wrong with my squeeze() function. The purpose of the function is to delete any characters in string 1 that are found in string 2. Right now all my function does is delete the first char of string1 if it's found in string2 and then acts strangely after that.. I looked in the answer book and the answer given is very confusing to me. It's hard to make sense of what is being done, so instead of following the logic in the answer book I sort of want to know where I'm going wrong in my own code... Here's the code below:

```
/* Write an alternate version of squeeze(s1, s2) that deletes each char in s1 that matches
*  any char in string s2 */

/* Here's a reference for squeeze(s1, s2):
*  squeeze: delete all c from s
*
*  void squeeze(char s[], int c)
*  {
*   int i, j;
*
*   for(i = j = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
*       if(s[i] != c)
*           s[j++] = s[i];
*   s[j] = '\0';
*  }
*******************************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_INPUT 100

void squeeze(char string1[], char string2[]);

int main()
{
    int c, i = 0, j = 0;
    char s1[MAX_INPUT + 2], s2[MAX_INPUT + 2];
    printf("\nPlease enter string1\n");
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        s1[i] = c;
        i++;
    }
    s1[i] = '\0';
    /* test to see if above worked */
    printf("\ns1 = %s\n", s1);

        printf("\nPlease enter string2\n");
        while((c = getchar()) != '\n')
        {
                s2[j] = c;
                j++;
        }
    s2[j] = '\0';
        /* test to see if above worked */
        printf("\ns2 = %s\n", s2);

    printf("\nWe will now apply the squeeze function to remove any chars");
    printf(" found in string2 from string1\n");
    squeeze(s1, s2);
    printf("Squeeze(s1, s2) = %s\n", s1);
}

void squeeze(char s1[], char s2[])
{
    int i = 0, j = 1;   /* for counters */
    char temp;  /* for char comparison */
    temp = s2[0];

    while(s2[i] != '\0')
    {
        if(s1[i] == temp)
        {
            s1[i] = s1[i+1];
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            j++;
        }
        temp = s2[j];
        i++;
    }
    s1[i+1] = '\0';

}
```

My output is the following:

```
Please enter string1
hello

s1 = hello

Please enter string2
help

s2 = help

We will now apply the squeeze function to remove any chars found in string2 from string1
Squeeze(s1, s2) = eello
```

Can anyone spot what's wrong with my logic? From the answer book I'm guessing I need a third counter, k, somewhere but I can't see a reason for it with the way I programmed the function.. I know I'm missing something though! Thanks so much everyone :)

Answer ( thank you Vlad!) :

```
void squeeze(char s1[], char s2[])
{
        int i = 0, j = 0;

        do
        {
                int k = 0;
                while(s2[k] != '\0' && s2[k] != s1[i])
                ++k;

                if (s2[k] == '\0')
                {
                        if ( j != i)
                                s1[j] = s1[i];
                ++j;
                }
        } while (s1[i++] != '\0');

}
```

Comment: What your while loop is doing is iterating string `s2`, but it checks only one value of the first string with the `if`, you need another loop inside the `while` the does the checking for all elements of `s1`, not just one at index `i`.

Comment: You seem to be using `i` and `j` in your function completely arbitrarily. Perhaps you need to step back and attempt to work out the logic by hand carefully. At least write a bit of prose that explains exactly what you think your code is doing. And year, K&R is humbling on the first go-around.

Comment: @MatteoPinna Isn't the i++ at the end incrementing the i in the while loop and the if statement?

Comment: Your debug print statements are good.  You are testing each section before going on to the next one.  Next step is to learn to use a debugger like gdb  so that you can step through the code and look at variables.

Comment: @JStone It does, but what's the point? Let's take the first iteration as an example, when `i=0`. So you're considering the first element of `s2` which is `h`. After this you check the first element of `s1` (`s1[0] = h`) in your `if` statement, they're equal you "remove" it. After this you increment `i` and you start your `while` loop again so you're considering the second element of `s2`. You checked only if the first element of `s1` was equal to `h`, not all of them, get it?

Comment: @MatteoPinna Yes! That makes a lot of sense actually.. I can see where I went wrong now.. I'm going to try and work through the logic of the below answer and see if I can figure out how to fix my own code with it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @stark I'm actually using the cmd line in linux to program. But I'm starting to think that programming on visual studio again might be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function does not make a sense.

The while loop is executed according to the length of s2

```
while(s2[i] != '\0')
```

However you are using the same index `i` for checking the string `s1`.

```
if(s1[i] == temp)
```

But the string `s1` can be in general shorter or larger than the string `s2`. So the function can invoke undefined behavior.

Also each character in `s1`  shall be checked in the string `s2` starting from its beginning.

The function can be declared and defined (without using standard C string functions) as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * squeeze( char s1[], const char s2[] )
{
    if ( *s2 != '\0' )
    {
        size_t i = 0;
        size_t j = 0;

        do
        {
            size_t k = 0;
            while ( s2[k] != '\0' && s2[k] != s1[i] ) ++k;
            
            if ( s2[k] == '\0' )
            {
                if ( j != i ) s1[j] = s1[i];
                ++j;
            }
        } while ( s1[i++] != '\0' );
    }
    
    return s1;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s1[] = "Hello World!"; 
    const char *s2 = "aeiou";
    
    puts( s1 );
    puts( squeeze( s1, s2 ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello World!
Hll Wrld!
```

Comment: It is a very elegant answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Vlad. I'm still a little confused on what the if ( j != i ) s1[j] = s1[i]; statement does though.. If you don't mind, can you (or anyone else) explain what this is doing? Thank you guys so much for all the help. This answer is definitely easier to follow along than the answer given in the book. I feel like I'm "almost" there at getting it.

Comment: @JStone You could just write s1[j++] = s1[i]; But if i is equal to j then there is no need to copy a character into itself. It is enough to increase j to set the next position for the next unique character.

Comment: Excellent! I fully understand now. I also took stark's above advice and downloaded gdb and was able to step through the code to see the logic now.. Very well done solution! Thank you so much for all your time and effort on this. I feel like I really made some progress by posting this question and getting everyone's help.

Answer (score 1):

I used `tmp` buffer to copy not containing characters. It is simpler and you can check it.

```c
void squeeze(char s1[], char s2[]){
    int i, j, k = 0;
    char* tmp;
    
    // tmp buffer initial size can be maximum s1 length
    tmp = malloc(strlen(s1) + 1);
    
    // loop until s1 character is null
    i = 0;
    while(s1[i] != '\0'){
        // loop until character is found or to the end.
        // break if s2 reached to the end or s1[i] == s2[j]
        j = 0;
        while(s2[j] != '\0' && s2[j] != s1[i]){
            j++;
        }
        
        // if j reached to the end, add into tmp buffer
        if(s2[j] == '\0'){
            // set current character
            tmp[k] = s1[i];
            // increase index
            k++;
        } else {
            printf("Found %c\n", s1[i]);
        }
        
        // next character
        i++;
    }
    // last character must be null
    tmp[k] = '\0';
    
    // tmp copy to s1
    strcpy(s1, tmp);
    
    // free tmp buffer
    free(tmp);
}
```